# How to use sbt plugin for a subproject in multi build prjoect

Tags: scala, sbt, gitlab-ci

I have a Scala project that is dependent on a Java project(child project).
My project structure is :
[image]

I am using GitLab to download some depedency jars for my project and I am using GitlabPlugin.

My build.sbt:

```
 lazy val root = Project("root-proj", file(".")).dependsOn(childProj)
    lazy val childProj = Project("child", file("child")).settings(
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.jdom" % "jdom" % "1.1.3",
        "commons-lang" % "commons-lang" % "2.6",
        "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % Test,
        "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % Test
      ),
      Compile / compile / javacOptions += "-g",
      Compile / packageDoc / mappings := Seq()
    )
    
    ThisBuild / useCoursier := false
    enablePlugins(GitlabPlugin)
    
    import com.gilcloud.sbt.gitlab.{GitlabCredentials, GitlabPlugin}
    GitlabPlugin.autoImport.gitlabDomain := "gitlab.com"
    GitlabPlugin.autoImport.gitlabCredentials := {
    sys.env.get("CI_JOB_TOKEN") match {
    // Gitlab CI pipeline
    case Some(t) =>
      Some(GitlabCredentials("Job-Token", t))
    // local machine
    case None =>
      val c = Credentials
        .loadCredentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / ".credentials.gitlab")
        .left
        .map(s => new IllegalArgumentException(s))
        .toTry
        .get
      Some(GitlabCredentials(c))
  }
}
```

My plugins.sbt has this line: `addSbtPlugin("com.gilcloud" % "sbt-gitlab" % "0.1.2")`

I am able to build the root project successfully if it is not dependent on Child project by commenting `.dependsOn(childProj)` and `childProj` variable.

But if use the Child project to build, I get the following errors:

```
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last child / headerAuthHandler' for the full output
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last ssExtractDependencies' for the full output
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last child / ssExtractDependencies' for the full output
[error] (child / headerAuthHandler) java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
[error] (ssExtractDependencies) java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
[error] (child / ssExtractDependencies) java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
```

This works fine If I run using GitLab pipeline, the issue is while trying to build locally using IntelliJ.

How do I tell my child project to use GitlabPlugin and use all GitlabPlugin statements?
I tried using `Project("child", file("child")).enablePlugins(GitlabPlugin).settings(...`
but still the same issue.

Comment: Could you clarify what commands you're using to build?

Comment: I just click on the refresh icon (Load sbt Changes) in my build.sbt file to reload or package in sbt-shell in Intellij.

Comment: Just to be sure: you do have a file  with credentials at `~/.sbt/.credentials.gitlab`, right? I don't see why it would fail only when building the subproject.

Comment: Yes I have that credentials file, if I dont have that file I would have got the error for root project too..  So I am guessing some how the child project is not able to refer to GitlabPlugin and its respective commands

Comment: I don't get why you think the child project doesn't have the gitlab plugin enabled. If it didn't, it wouldn't even try to execute the definition of `gitlabCredentials`.

Comment: If I comment the following code
`.dependsOn(childProj)
    lazy val childProj = Project("child", file("child")).settings(
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.jdom" % "jdom" % "1.1.3",
        "commons-lang" % "commons-lang" % "2.6",
        "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % Test,
        "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % Test
      ),
      Compile / compile / javacOptions += "-g",
      Compile / packageDoc / mappings := Seq()
    )`
I am able to build root project.. so I assume child is not able to use that plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the line

```
credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / ".credentials.gitlab")
```

to my child project settings and it started working. This may be specific to `sbt-gitlab` plugin.